# Select Distinct Sum - GROUP BY

Tags: sql, sql-server, vb.net, select

```
SELECT DISTINCT [SC Vermorel SRL$Production Order].No_, 
                [SC Vermorel SRL$Production Order].[Replan Ref_ No_], 
                [SC Vermorel SRL$Production Order].Description, 
                [SC Vermorel SRL$Production Order].[Source No_], 
                [SC Vermorel SRL$Production Order].[Routing No_], 
                [SC Vermorel SRL$Production Order].Quantity, 
                [SC Vermorel SRL$Production Order].[Old Prod_ Order No_], 
                [SC Vermorel SRL$Routing Line].[Run Time], 
                [SC Vermorel SRL$Routing Line].[Run Time] * [SC Vermorel SRL$Production Order].Quantity AS TotalOre, 
                [SC Vermorel SRL$Prod_ Order Line].[Finished Quantity], 
                SUM([SC Vermorel SRL$ProductieZilnica].[Cantitate sudura]) AS [Cantitate sudura], 
                SUM([SC Vermorel SRL$ProductieZilnica].[Cantitate montaj]) AS [Cantitate montaj]
FROM [SC Vermorel SRL$Production Order] 
INNER JOIN [SC Vermorel SRL$Routing Line] 
    ON [SC Vermorel SRL$Production Order].[Routing No_] = [SC Vermorel SRL$Routing Line].[Routing No_] 
INNER JOIN [SC Vermorel SRL$Prod_ Order Line] 
    ON [SC Vermorel SRL$Production Order].No_ = [SC Vermorel SRL$Prod_ Order Line].[Prod_ Order No_] 
INNER JOIN [SC Vermorel SRL$ProductieZilnica] 
    ON [SC Vermorel SRL$Production Order].No_ = [SC Vermorel SRL$ProductieZilnica].RPO
WHERE ([SC Vermorel SRL$Production Order].Status = 3) 
        AND ([SC Vermorel SRL$Production Order].[Location Code] = 'MACH FIN') 
        AND ([SC Vermorel SRL$Production Order].[Gen_ Prod_ Posting Group] = 'FINISHED G') 
        AND ([SC Vermorel SRL$Routing Line].No_ = '150')
GROUP BY [SC Vermorel SRL$Production Order].No_
```

I need to attach the sum of all the entries from another table (`[SC Vermorel SRL$ProductieZilnica]`) which corresponds to each distinct `No_` from `[SC Vermorel SRL$Production Order]` table.

I cant for the love of God make it work. Can someone point me in the right direction?

Comment: sql server 2005. this is written in the query builder from vsstudio 2015.

Comment: Have you ever used the AS keyword to simplify your names?

Comment: distinct and group by in the same query is pointless, the group by will make it distinct. In the group by you must write every column that is in your select (except functions like max, min, sum,...) Your query does not do that and therefore it wont even work but return errors.

Comment: Start by making your query shorter and more readable by using alias for each table. No one is going to read all this

Answer (score 3, accepted):

At first, use table [aliases](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187455(v=sql.105).aspx) - it will make your query more readable.

If you are using GROUP BY you need to add all columns, except one that are in aggregation function (you got SUM) like:

```
SELECT  PO.No_, 
        PO.[Replan Ref_ No_], 
        PO.[Description], 
        PO.[Source No_], 
        PO.[Routing No_], 
        PO.Quantity, 
        PO.[Old Prod_ Order No_], 
        RL.[Run Time], 
        RL.[Run Time] * PO.Quantity AS TotalOre, 
        POL.[Finished Quantity], 
        SUM(PZ.[Cantitate sudura]) AS [Cantitate sudura], 
        SUM(PZ.[Cantitate montaj]) AS [Cantitate montaj]
FROM  [SC Vermorel SRL$Production Order] PO
INNER JOIN [SC Vermorel SRL$Routing Line] RL
    ON PO.[Routing No_] = RL.[Routing No_] 
INNER JOIN [SC Vermorel SRL$Prod_ Order Line] POL
    ON PO.No_ = POL.[Prod_ Order No_] 
INNER JOIN [SC Vermorel SRL$ProductieZilnica] PZ
    ON PO.No_ = PZ.RPO
WHERE     (PO.Status = 3) AND (PO.[Location Code] = 'MACH FIN') AND 
                  (PO.[Gen_ Prod_ Posting Group] = 'FINISHED G') AND (RL.No_ = '150')
GROUP BY PO.No_,
        PO.[Replan Ref_ No_], 
        PO.[Description], 
        PO.[Source No_], 
        PO.[Routing No_], 
        PO.Quantity, 
        PO.[Old Prod_ Order No_], 
        RL.[Run Time], 
        PO.Quantity, 
        POL.[Finished Quantity]
```

Comment: thank you very much for the answer and for all the advices. very kind. as always, i am an idiot and, although is the right answer for my question in the way that I asked, i still need one more advice: this query, in the way that I asked, only outputs the entries which have values on the sum columns. What I actually wanted was to display all the entries from PO table, even they have or not a value on the sum columns from PZ table. Thanks alot again all of you! My next post will be much cleaner.

Comment: My pleasure! If you need ALL from PO, change all INNER JOIN to LEFT JOIN, in that case there may be NULLs in RL, POL and SZ columns. INNER JOIN - gets all values that are in both tables, LEFT JOIN show all values but if there are no corespondent rows in the second table - it will show NULLs.

Comment: Works like a charm! This is a great community! Thanks again.